# How can I get the value of a async and pass to a function?

Tags: javascript, fs

I need to get the value of mtime and return as result of lastSave function but i get undefined. I know I can use fs.statSync("./Data.xlsx") to get this value. I'm using fs.stat() as example for async inside a function.

```
const lastSave = async (file) => {
    const momento = await fs.stat(file, function (err, stats) {
        var mtime = stats.mtime;
        console.log("interno", mtime);    // this works
        return mtime
    });
    return momento
}

console.log(lastSave('./Data.xlsx'))  // this writes "undefined"
```

Comment: `lastSave` is an _async_ function which means that it returns a Promise. To get its return value, either chain a `then()` method: `lastSave('./Data.xlsx').then(data => console.log(data)).catch(e => console.log(e));` or call this function in another async function and `await` it.

Comment: Also consider using Promise-based API of `fs` module. Currently you are using the callback API which doesn't returns a Promise, so awaiting `fs.stat` won't work. You could create a new Promise using Promise constructor but using the Promise-based API of `fs` module is the way to go.

Comment: You need the promise version of `fs.stat()` in order to use `await`. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_promise_example

Comment: @Yousaf Not going to work since OP is using a callback in `fs.stat()`

Comment: @charlietfl yes i mentioned that in my second comment that OP needs to use the Promise-based API of `fs` module.

Comment: yes, I did not wrote but I'm using require('fs')

Comment: `require('fs') ` does not include the promise versions needed to use `await`. You can't arbitrarily use `await` for asynchronous methods that use a callback. See link above that shows using `require('fs/promises')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sync variant of the function.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const lastSave = file => {
    return fs.statSync(file).mtime;
}

console.log(lastSave('./Data.xlsx'));
```

If there is no sync version wrap the call in a async function and call it:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const lastSave = file => {
    return new Promise(done => fs.stat(file, function (err, stats) {
        var mtime = stats.mtime;
        console.log("interno", mtime);    // this works
        done(mtime);
    }));
}

(async () => {
    console.log(await lastSave('./Data.xlsx'));
})();
```

You can use the promise-based variant:

```
const fs = require('fs/promises');

const lastSave = async file => {
    return (await fs.stat(file)).mtime;
}

(async () => {
    console.log(await lastSave('./Data.xlsx'));
})();
```

Alternatively you can [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) your async function:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const lastSave = async file => {
    return (await util.promisify(fs.stat)(file)).mtime;
}

(async () => {
    console.log(await lastSave('./Data.xlsx'));
})();
```

Alternatives for

```
(async () => {
    console.log(await lastSave('./Data.xlsx'));
})();
```

are

```
lastSave('./Data.xlsx').then(console.log);
```

and

```
lastSave('./Data.xlsx').then(result => { console.log(result); });
```

Comment: I believe you mean *"use the **async** version"*

Comment: @charlietfl No, I mean _"Use the sync variant"_ as in `fs.statSync`.

Comment: My bad... I missed that *example* part